# Internal and External services on a single proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've got an Nginx reverse proxy handling application traffic, and there's been a request to tack on some new internal-only apps. The pre-existing solution was to just add the following to the `location` block:

```
allow 10.20.0.0/16;
deny all;
```

But that's never really sat well with me.

I assumed that I would be able to change `listen 443 ssl;` to `listen 10.20.0.1:443 ssl;` to stop nginx from responding with even a 401 on the external interface. eg:

```
server {
  listen 10.20.0.1:443 ssl;
  server_name foo-app.internal.corp.com;
  location { ... }
  ...
}
```

However this seems to have overridden all other configured simple `listen 443;` directives, and requests to the internal address serve *only* this new application.

Is there a way to ensure that *all* configured sites are served as-usual, as well as restrict internal sites as desired?

Comment: If it were me, I'd have this sort of thing on completely separate networks to begin with.  It's easy for a config file to go wrong, and accidentally expose too much.  If for some reason this is not at all an option, I think you're going the right direction by ensuring it can only listen on certain interfaces for serving internal traffic.  The problem you're running into is a conflict between binding on that internal interface and all interfaces.  Can you just add an extra IP address to the server for those internal apps?  And then they can't conflict.